# Loop constantly restarting

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am new to Intel x86 assembly - this is actually the first program I am writing for it.

I am trying to use a loop that is similar to this:

```
mov ecx,5
numLoop:
[OTHER CODE - DOESN'T OVERWRITE ECX]
loop numLoop
```

This looks fine to me, however it just loops forever in the output and I cannot figure out why. I do not alter the value of `ECX` at all during the extra code.

Comment: Show the code in between, you properly have some `call` to a function that changes `ecx`.

Comment: @BSH, all I call is printf and scanf. Could either of these affect it?

Comment: Yes they do, some functions may save all the values of the registers on the stack first, but to be safe, save the value of the register first before you call it.

Comment: `printf` and `scanf` uses `cdecl` convention. That means `eax`, `ecx`, `edx` may be clobbered after function call.

Answer (score 1):

Little trick: When you use `loop` you should `push` `ecx` to stack before your code and than before `loop` call you should pop it out from stack like that.

```
mov ecx,5
numLoop:
push ecx
[OTHER CODE - DOESN'T OVERWRITE ECX]
pop ecx
loop numLoop
```

Comment: If the code *actually* doesn't overwrite ECX, you don't need push/pop.  If it does (e.g. a function call), you should pick a different register, like EBX or ESI, and use `dec ebx / jnz` instead of `loop`.  push+pop+loop is 4 bytes, vs. 3 bytes for dec+jnz, so `loop` still loses on the only thing its good for (code size, [not speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)) if you have to push/pop.